# firebase get data query is returning with empty docs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all the data of the current user from a collection called "users" but the docs in the response the docs is empty.
here is the function I'm using

```
const getUser = async ()=> {
  let current_user = (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid); // get the user uid
    if(current_user){
      let userDB = db.collection("users")
      let userDataref = await userDB.where("user_id", "==", `${current_user}`).get();
      let userData = userDataref.docs.map(doc => doc.data()) //get all the fields for current user
      console.log(userData)
    }
}
```

[image: this is the database]

[image: debugger screen]

There is data in the `userDataref`, but `docs` is empty.

Comment: i have few doubts. why are you using `current_user` in template literals.
and also `userDataref.docs` is `undefined` in the image.

Comment: Are you supposed to be using `firestore.getDocs(userDataref)` ?

Comment: @MuhammedJabir that was just a last attempt I know it doesn't change anything I've tried it with template literals and without it, and yes the `userDataref.docs` is undefined

Comment: @TjadClark I've tried it with `getDocs` and it shows the same result

Comment: @AyushPatel Just for absolute clarity, you awaited the `getDocs(userDataref)` call and then mapped it ? Something like this:  `(await getDocs(userDataref)).map((doc)=>doc.data())`

Comment: are you using namespaced API or modular API, if namespaced API `db.collection("cities").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});`  is this how you tried it ?

Comment: have you checked your firestore rules ?

Comment: @MuhammedJabir Guys thank you for your help, but I figured out the problem, for some reason in the authentication tab on firebase there were 4 users and in the database there were only 3 users. The problem was that 2 users had the same email and password, but different uid, when I was trying to login it was logging in with the ID that was not in the database, I don't know why there were two different users made for the same email, and why they were not added to the database. But it worked, there was nothing wrong with the code